# Checkbox data not passing in other activity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass the position of checkbox present in my listview to another activity with the help of an intent. But it shows me null at another activity. Or can someone tell me how can i pass the selected checkbox data to another activity using the code below?

I want to store value in an array from the listview of the respective check box. and then transfer to another activity

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {
int getPosition;
Intent in;
private final List<Model> list;
public final Activity context;
boolean checkAll_flag = false;
boolean checkItem_flag = false;

public MyAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.row, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView text;
    protected CheckBox checkbox;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.check);
        viewHolder.checkbox
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                         getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag(); // setTag.

                    }
                });
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new MyCustomItemClickListener(getPosition));

        convertView.setTag(R.id.label, viewHolder.text);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.check, viewHolder.checkbox);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(position); // This line is important.

    viewHolder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());

    return convertView;
}

class MyCustomItemClickListener implements OnClickListener {

    MyCustomItemClickListener(int getPositionx) {
        /*
         * Whatever initialization you need can be done here. You can pass
         * values in constructor when calling it from getview and use with
         * intent extras
         */
         in = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
         in.putExtra("aa", getPositionx);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // Launch Activity

        context.startActivity(in);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass the checkbox text to another activity or checkbox position?

Comment: How you are extracting the value from intent? Can you show that code, coz you are actually getting null in that code, isn't it?

Comment: I want to store value in an array from the listview of the respective check box. and then transfer to another activity

Answer (score 0):

try it out as Below way. No Need to Pass `getPositionx` inside Constructor as you have already define it globally in your class.

```
class MyCustomItemClickListener implements OnClickListener {

    MyCustomItemClickListener() {
        /*
         * Whatever initialization you need can be done here. You can pass
         * values in constructor when calling it from getview and use with
         * intent extras
         */

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // Launch Activity

   in = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
         in.putExtra("aa", getPositionx);

        context.startActivity(in);
    }

}
```

and Change your Initialization to

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new MyCustomItemClickListener());
```

Answer (score 0):

Declear getPosition as a static variable and you can access
 the value MyAdapter.getPosition to the another activity

```
public static getPosition;
```

and the activity where you want to access this variable

```
MyAdapter.getPosition use this.
```

but the way you are passing the value that is also wright but before passing
  it to the intent check weather your value is not null,in this case

```
getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
```

is not able to get the values.